# The label that's applied to this item prevents it from being moved or renamed. Check the item's label for more details

Tags: sharepoint-online, retention, copy-item

Hi all I have written a WF which copy a document from one library to another but now copy action is not working as destination library labeling have been done
Is there any way to replace the new version of the file without removing it from the label?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "destination library labelling have been done"? Could you clarify on that? Does it mean destination library has been renamed?

Comment: retention label have been applied so if I try to copy it throw error

Comment: Can't you use **[Move file]** action in your Flow? MS documentation [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/retention?view=o365-worldwide) states "Retention Label" persists if documents move within Microsoft 365 tenant

Comment: move is working fine but if I want to use copy action and want to update  exist document it throw error it cannot be renamed and moved label prevent it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could recreate your issue on my own tenant: if a retention label is set on a document, Power Automate will not let you copy to that document. However, through the UI is is indeed possible. Strange.

If you in your Power Automate flow instead of Copy File use Create file it will. Below is a screen shot of a test flow that grabs the content of the source file and creates the file at the target library. One thing to remember here is that in order to overwrite the existing target document you need to set Allow Chunking off by clicking Settings on the Create file action and set to off (also screen shotted this one).

[image]

[image]

Comment: @kumar let me know if this one solves your issue

Comment: let me check and will get back to you if its worked

Comment: Thanks it works!